# Handling Oath 2.0 Authorization from Backend Job

Tags: android, rest, backend

I am trying to find a solution to the following:

**Requirments**

1. There is exists an app that allows users to add integration providers
2. These integration providers use oath 2.0 authorization to secure their data
3. The app needs the ability to have a backend job fetch data on-behalf of the user once per day
4. The data fetched is ingested and merged into a report that is compiled on the app for the user

**Problem**

1. **User Delegated Access Token from Backend Job** - I'm having trouble finding the solution that allows me to have a valid access token that is on behalf of the user without having to generate the access token from the app side

**What I have tried**

1. **Refresh Token** - I have tried the approach of using the refresh token to constantly get a new access token but this solution is fragile in the sense that there might be a situation that a new token is not generated in time or for some reason the user still needs to reauthenticate the connection to the provider
2. **Automated Browser Flows** - I have tried automating the user's authentication flow from the backend using saved credentials given in the app. This approach is just sketchy, costly, and would require a lot of work on the user agreement side ensuring that is being done on the backend has been consented by the user which essentially reinvents the wheel on user consent which the identity providers should have already been handling

Answer (score 0):

We can use JWT for this. By doing it with JWT we'll create a token and save to the database and on every request it will decrypt the token and get the required data from the token.

Link- https://jwt.io/